# 12.04 LTS 64 bit - Login Screen - Broken Pipe / No Graphical Interface

Tags: graphics, login

For two times, I did a clean install on my notebook (which as an NDVIDIA GT610M GPU), and for both times I did the following:

1 - Check for updates / Install
2 - Reboot
3 - apt-get install audacious open-jdk7 pidgin deluge wine ntfs-config
4 - Reboot

In both times, after the reboot I get: "unable to write pipes, broken pipe", and then after another reboot, I just do not have graphical interface (just the command line).

What can I do? I checked some similar questions but found no usefull response.

Comment: I realized that the problem is that wine in some manner messes with the xorg configuration, so the question is: how to control that.

Answer (score 0):

Since your in the command line try typing `startx`. If that doesn't work try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, not.